# C sockets error

Tags: c, sockets, client, pthreads, semaphore

For some reason this line of code is giving me quite a problem.

```
struct socketaddr_in clientaddr;
```

The error message is:

```
tiny.c:23:24: error: storage size of ‘clientaddr’ isn’t known
```

If I remove that line of code I get the following error message:

```
s2s2@s2s2-ThinkPad-T61:~/Documents/Cprogramming/web_server$ make
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -lpthread -lrt -o server tiny.c csapp.c
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `Pthread_create':
csapp.c:(.text+0x7e5): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `Pthread_cancel':
csapp.c:(.text+0x805): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `Pthread_join':
csapp.c:(.text+0x825): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `Pthread_detach':
csapp.c:(.text+0x845): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `Sem_init':
csapp.c:(.text+0x895): undefined reference to `sem_init'
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `P':
csapp.c:(.text+0x8b5): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `V':
csapp.c:(.text+0x8d5): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/tmp/ccVxw07i.o: In function `Pthread_once':
csapp.c:(.text+0x881): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [webServer-gcc] Error 1
```

Here are links to the [csapp.c](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece845/sp02/csapp.c) and [csapp.h](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece845/sp02/csapp.h) files.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Please post *minimal code reproducing the problem* and not links to thousand lines long files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> tiny.c:23:24: error: storage size of ‘clientaddr’ isn’t known

There's a reason you need to declare structs as `struct structname instancename` in C - that's so that the C compiler knows how much memory to allocate - and possibly how to align that data, etc.

This is the C compiler's way of telling you no such struct `socketaddr_in` exists - it'd be `sockaddr_in`.

A common way to work around the naming of structs in this way is to define them like this:

```
typedef struct _struct_name
{
    /* ... */
} structname;
```

then `structname` can be used as a type without the `struct` qualifier. You don't have to do this on the definition of the struct, either, you could do it later.

So, the short answer is `socketaddr_in` doesn't exist as a struct in POSIX - it's `sockaddr_in`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get the error with all the pthreads can you help me out there?